# MySQL Replication Over SSH - Last_IO_Errno: 2003 - error connecting to master

Tags: mysql, ssh, mysql-replication

I have MySQL MASTER/SLAVE replication working on two test boxes (Centos 6.4 / MySQL 5.5.32) over LAN.

Securing the connection over ssh causes connection problems from the SLAVE machine:

(Sample of **show slave status \G** Output)

**Last_IO_Errno: 2003
Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'rep@127.0.0.1:3305' - retry-time: 60**

I have granted the replication user the relevant privileges on the master server with both 127.0.0.1 and the network IP.

I have forwarded the port from slave to master over SSH

**ssh -f 192.168.0.128 -L 3305:192.168.0.128:3306 -N**

I can connect to master MySQL from slave with

**mysql -urep -ppassword -h127.0.0.1 -P3305**

The master server setup would seem fine, as it works without a tunnel, and the tunnel seems fine, as I can connect to MySQL between the two.

Change Master Statement:

**CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='127.0.0.1', MASTER_PORT=3305, MASTER_USER='rep', MASTER_PASSWORD='password';**

Note: I know there are reasons to use SSL, instead of SSH, but I have reasons why SSH is a better choice for my setup.

Comment: What parameters did you enter exactly in the CHANGE MASTER TO: statement?

Comment: CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='127.0.0.1', MASTER_PORT=3305, MASTER_USER='rep', MASTER_PASSWORD='password';

Comment: anything in your master mysql log file?

Comment: You have added the binlog and log file position as well right?

Comment: Nothing in master mysql.log for several hours preceding my attempts.

Comment: I've tried with and without binlog and log file position.

Comment: Just as a test, if you create a 'repl@%' user, to see if for some odd reason it sees the replication connection as coming from somewhere else than 127.0.0.1 or the slave's ip?

Comment: I have tried that, but the error remains the same.

Comment: Could you show output of the "mysql> show grants for rep;"

Comment: ---------------------------------+
| Grants for rep@%                                                                                               |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'rep'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*657E646B9082070505D0291D1644F9B3BD3D58CC' |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: That doesn't display quite right here. The 'SLAVE ON . ' is actually 'SLAVE ON (asterisk).(asterisk)'

Comment: I can't submit my own answer, yet, but to save other people's time, it turns out the issue was SELinux not allowing MySQL on a non-standard port.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your help, guys, but it turns out the issue was SELinux not allowing MySQL on a non-standard port.

Comment: Silly SELinux..

Comment: +1 for finding you own answer.

Comment: Aaaa damn you SELinux! @Dom if I could I would give you any bounty there was! Thanks a lot! After 4 days of searching high and low, this was it! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use semanage to allow additional none standard port for mysqld

```
sudo /usr/sbin/semanage port -a -t mysqld_port_t -p tcp 3305
```

then you may verify using

```
sudo /usr/sbin/semanage port -l | grep mysql
```

you'll see the new port displayed along with the standard port 3306

mysqld_port_t                  tcp      3305, 3306, 63132-63164